# How to know which Toggle Buttons are clicked from dynamically added view?

Tags: java, android

This is my first time with android programming and I got stuck.

Now I'm trying to add view dynamically which contains toggle buttons, and edittext. However, whenever I select toggle button, options I created only works on last created view.

Options are simple. There are two toggle buttons and they can be clicked mutually exclusive

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dX4vO.png)

which means whenever I add new views such as B and C in above, the options are only worked on C while not in B. How can I make it to work on every view?

```
public void onAddField(View v){
    LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.data_gledger_add_new,null);

    tbg_add=(ToggleButton)rowView.findViewById(R.id.add_toggle_gledger);
    tbc_add=(ToggleButton)rowView.findViewById(R.id.add_toggle_credit);

    if(create_box<4){
        csl.addView(rowView,csl.getChildCount()-1);
        Log.d("create_box",String.valueOf(create_box));
        create_box++;
    }
    else{
        Log.d("create_box","full");
        create_box=4;
    }

    tbg_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            if(tbg_add.isChecked()){
                get_add_cla="menu1";
                tbg_add.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_white));
                tbc_add.setChecked(false);
                tbc_add.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_black));
            }
            else{
                get_add_cla="";
                tbg_add.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_black));
            }
        }
    });

    //대변 선택
    tbc_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            if(tbc_add.isChecked()){
                get_add_cla="menu2";
                tbc_add.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_white));
                tbg_add.setChecked(false);
                tbg_add.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_black));
            }
            else{
                get_add_cla="";
                tbc_add.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_black));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I forgot to mention that views are added by clicking button.
    android:onClick="onAddField"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem almost certainly stems from the fact that you are re-using instance fields (`tbg_add` and `tbc_add`) as add new views dynamically.

> ```
> tbg_add=(ToggleButton)rowView.findViewById(R.id.add_toggle_gledger);
> tbc_add=(ToggleButton)rowView.findViewById(R.id.add_toggle_credit);
> ```

Because you are re-assigning these fields and also referencing them from the click listeners, you'll always be referencing the most recently created toggle buttons.

Change these to be local variables and everything should work fine.

```
ToggleButton ledger=(ToggleButton)rowView.findViewById(R.id.add_toggle_gledger);
ToggleButton credit=(ToggleButton)rowView.findViewById(R.id.add_toggle_credit);
```

---

Unrelated to your problem, but also something you should fix, is the fact that you're passing `null` as the second parameter to your `inflate()` call:

> ```
> final View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.data_gledger_add_new,null);
> ```

When you pass `null` in this manner, the system won't have any ability to correctly handle the `LayoutParams` (anything starting with `android:layout_` in the xml file) for the newly-inflated view.

You know that you're going to wind up adding the `rowView` to your `csl` view, so you should pass that as the second parameter. Once you do that, you also have to pass `false` as a third parameter to make sure that the `inflate()` call actually returns the `rowView` and not its new parent (`csl`).

```
final View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.data_gledger_add_new, csl, false);
```

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: umm mind if i ask you one more thing? now im trying to set value for "get_add_cla" in above question. but if i set value in above manner, no matter how many view i create, every value for get_add_cla is set depends on last view created. i tried to store in array but it doesn't work